# What is the procedure for showing a vector function is onto?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Say for example $(x + y,\ y + z,\ x +z)$ or $(\sin x,\ \cos y)$ or $(e^x,\ e^y,\ e^z)$ in $\mathbb R^2 \rightarrow\mathbb R^2$ or $\mathbb R^3 \rightarrow \mathbb R^3$, etc. I provided multiple examples because I want to know how to show in general that any function is surjective; These aren't actually problems I want to solve (though I probably will as practice).

Comment: In this generality? Show for each opint that it is in the image of the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, one picks an arbitrary point in the range, say $(a,b,c)$ and then goes and finds a point in the domain, say $(x,y,z)$ such that $f(x,y,z)=(a,b,c)$

For example, consider $f(x,y,z)=(x^3,y,z-y-x)$. Then $x=a^\frac{1}{3},y=b$ are easy. This give that $c=z-b-a^\frac{1}{3}$. Thus $z=c+b+a^\frac{1}{3}$. This gives that $f(a^\frac{1}{3},b,c+b+a^\frac{1}{3})=(a,b,c)$, so $(a,b,c)$ are in the range. But $a,b$ and $c$ are arbitrary, and this function can be evaluated everywhere - compare to if we had had $x^2$, then we wouldn't be able to evaluate at $a=-1$, and indeed such a function cannot attain the value $(-1,0,0)$ - so all of $\mathbb{R}^3$ is in the range so the function is surjective.

Comment: Just alerting a typo: in your last line it should be "the function is **surjective**", not _subjective_. =)

Comment: You are welcome!